# Notification on Property Change C#

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, twitter, queue

Hello I have a program with many background workers. Those background workers do nothing but listen on a change from a variable called "tweet" and then each backgrounder creates a task for each "tweet" to process it and be ready to handle another Tweet.

Below is the Tweet class which gets updated every 1 second or less.

```
  Tweet tweet = new Tweet();
    public class Tweet : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ITweet lastTweet;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
                handler(this, e);
        }

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        public ITweet LastTweet
        {
            get { return lastTweet; }
            set
            {
                if (value != lastTweet)
                {
                    lastTweet = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LastTweet");
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Now in my BackgroundWorker DoWork implementation:

```
        Del OnNewTweetEvent = delegate(object sender2, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            Task task = null;
            task = new Task(() =>
            {
                var mytweet = sender2 as Tweet;
                var tweetText = mytweet.LastTweet.Text;
                //copy the tweetText in case the mytweet variable changed ( not sure )
                ProcessTweet( tweetText );
            });
            task.Start();

        };
        this.tweet.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnNewTweetEvent);

        //wait and prepare for cancellation
        var backgroundworker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            if (backgroundworker.CancellationPending)
            {
                //remove the notification
                this.tweet.PropertyChanged -= new PropertyChangedEventHandler(OnNewTweetEvent);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Is this code logic right ? What if the tweets source tweets every 0.01 second, will I be able to get them all ? Or the tweet may change without my background workers getting it ?

Is it better to have a queue or something ?
Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you already suspect, the approach in your sample might not be able to catch every single tweet or guarantee that every tweet is only processed once. Therefore you should store them in a collection. A queue would be a good fit for this purpose.

A more straightforward approach would be to have a single background task watch the queue and start an asynchronous task that processes a new tweet in the queue.

However, someone needs to place the tweets in the queue (or in your sample update the properties of the Tweet object). So the easiest and best approach would be to start the asynchronous tasks right when a new tweet arrives. This eliminates the background task that waits for new tweets and by that removes a spot where the system can break.

Based upon you code sample, the following code shows an easy way to process a new tweet right when it arrives. You might want to move the code to another spot in your code and also rename the types as appropriate. Based upon your comments this sample also takes different actions for different tweet types into account:

```
// No need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged as there is no listener anymore
public class Tweet 
{
    private ITweet lastTweet;

    public ITweet LastTweet
    {
        get { return lastTweet; }
        set
        {
            if (value != lastTweet)
            {
                lastTweet = value;
                var actionForTweet = GetActionForTweet(lastTweet);
                Task task = new Task(() =>
                {
                    actionForTweet(lastTweet);
                });
                task.Start();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Action<ITweet> GetActionForTweet(ITweet tweet)
    {
        // Decide what to do for which kind of tweet
        // In the simplest case this is an if/switch statement
        if ( ... )
              return x => {
                              var tweetText = x.Text;
                              ProcessTweet( tweetText );
                          };
        else 
              return x => {
                              // Do something else
                          };
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you please provide some code edit to my current code on the best way to do it ?

Comment: @circler: I've added a small sample. Hope that it helps.

Comment: thanks for the code. What is the best way to do it as a collection because i would like to run it in a background worker because every worker has diff stuff to do.

Comment: @circler: I've updated the sample with the ability to do different things for different tweets. I don't think you need a queue. I don't know too much about your project so please don't expect a sample that fits without modification or adoption to your specific environment. Hope my thoughts help nevertheless.